# Django: Selecting distinct values on maximum foreign key value

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have the following models which I'm testing with SQLite3 and MySQL:

```
# (various model fields extraneous to discussion removed...)

class Run(models.Model):
    runNumber = models.IntegerField()

class Snapshot(models.Model):
    t = models.DateTimeField()

class SnapshotRun(models.Model):
    snapshot = models.ForeignKey(Snapshot)
    run = models.ForeignKey(Run)
    # other fields which make it possible to have multiple distinct Run objects per Snapshot
```

I want a query which will give me a set of runNumbers & snapshot IDs for which the Snapshot.id is below some specified value.  Naively I would expect this to work:

```
print SnapshotRun.objects.filter(snapshot__id__lte=ss_id)\
                         .order_by("run__runNumber", "-snapshot__id")\
                         .distinct("run__runNumber", "snapshot__id")\
                         .values("run__runNumber", "snapshot__id")
```

But this blows up with

```
NotImplementedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend
```

for both database backends.  Postgres is unfortunately not an option.

Time to fall back to raw SQL?

**Update**:

Since Django's ORM won't help me out of this one (thanks @jknupp) I did manage to get the following raw SQL to work:

```
cursor.execute("""
            SELECT r.runNumber, ssr1.snapshot_id
            FROM livedata_run AS r
            JOIN livedata_snapshotrun AS ssr1
            ON ssr1.id =
            (
                SELECT id
                FROM livedata_snapshotrun AS ssr2
                WHERE ssr2.run_id = r.id
                  AND ssr2.snapshot_id <= %s
                ORDER BY snapshot_id DESC
               LIMIT 1
            );
""", max_ss_id)
```

Here `livedata` is the Django app these tables live in.

Comment: So you want it to return a list of `runNumbers` where each row returned also contains a list of the (numerous) `snapshot` ids attached to it?

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony not quite; I want to get a single `snapshot_id`, the latest (but not exceeding `ss_id`) for every run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The note [in the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) is pretty clear:

> Note:
>
> Any fields used in an order_by() call are included in the SQL SELECT columns. This can sometimes lead to unexpected results when used in conjunction with distinct(). If order by fields from a related model, those fields will be added to the selected columns and they may make otherwise duplicate rows appear to be distinct. Since the extra columns don’t appear in the returned results (they are only there to support ordering), it sometimes looks like non-distinct results are being returned.
>
> Similarly, if you use a values() query to restrict the columns selected, the columns used in any order_by() (or default model ordering) will still be involved and may affect uniqueness of the results.
>
> The moral here is that if you are using distinct() be careful about ordering by related models. Similarly, when using distinct() and values() together, be careful when ordering by fields not in the values() call.

Also, below that:

> This ability to specify field names (with distinct) is only available in PostgreSQL.